# Java.util.ArrayList.sort() sorting algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I was looking at the source code of the [sort()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort1%28long%5b%5d%2Cint%2Cint%29) method of the [java.util.ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) on grepcode. They seem to use insertion sort on small arrays (of size < 7) and merge sort on large arrays. I was just wondering if that makes a lot of difference given that they use insertion sort only for arrays of size < 7. The difference in running time will be hardly noticeable on modern machines.

I have read this in Cormen:

> Although merge sort runs in O(n*logn) worst-case time and insertion sort runs in O(n*n) worst-case time, the constant factors in insertion sort can make it faster in practice for small problem sizes on many machines. Thus, it makes sense to coarsen the leaves of the recursion by using insertion sort within merge sort when subproblems become sufficiently small.

If I would have designed sorting algorithm for some component which I require, then I would consider using insertion-sort for greater sizes (maybe  upto size < 100) before the difference in running time, as compared to merge sort, becomes evident.

My question is what is the analysis behind arriving at size < 7?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> The difference in running time will be hardly noticeable on modern machines.

How long it takes to sort small arrays becomes very important when you realize that the overall sorting algorithm is recursive, and the small array sort is effectively the base case of that recursion.

I don't have any inside info on how the number seven got chosen. However, I'd be very surprised if that wasn't done as the result of benchmarking the competing algorithms on small arrays, and choosing the optimal algorithm and threshold based on that.

P.S. It is worth pointing out that Java7 uses [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) by default.

Comment: I am getting a bit of your point now. Suppose if we had a very large array, then recursively sorting it will divide the array into numerous small arrays. That is where I guess the efficiency of insertion sort kicks in to do its job.

Comment: Yup, I think that answers my question. Except I would need to analyze benchmarking results to believe in the concept of choosing size seven :)

Comment: @sultan.of.swing: If you really want to, you can easily copy-and-paste the sorting code into your own project, and run some benchmarks. :)

Comment: I don't know if this page of mine is interesting to the discussion: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/sorting_java_algorithm_performance_2.shtml

Comment: @NeilCoffey Your page is very helpful indeed. It gives good insight into sorting performance data which I was looking for. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this for people who visit this thread in future and documenting my own research. I stumbled across this excellent link in my quest to find the answer to the mystery of choosing 7:

[Tim Peters’s description of the algorithm](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt)

You should read the section titled "Computing minrun".

To give a gist, minrun is the cutoff size of the array below which the algorithm should start using insertion sort. Hence, we will always have sorted arrays of size "minrun" on which we will need to run merge operation to sort the entire array.

In java.util.ArrayList.sort(), "minrun" is chosen to be 7, but as far as my understanding of the above document goes, it busts that myth and shows that it should be near powers of 2 and less than 256 and more than 8. Quoting from the document:

> At 256 the data-movement cost in binary insertion sort clearly hurt, and at 8 the increase in the number of function calls clearly hurt.  Picking *some* power of 2 is important here, so that the merges end up perfectly balanced (see next section).

The point which I am making is that "minrun" can be any power of 2 (or near power of 2) less than 64, without hindering the performance of TimSort.

Comment: Why 'probably 64'? It seems strange to be so vague in a thread where you have been asking for 'analysis'.

Comment: @EJP I didn't mean to be vague. The linked document explains the concept beautifully. But I think you are correct, I will modify the answer a bit.

Answer (score -1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

"Timsort is a hybrid sorting algorithm, derived from merge sort and insertion sort, designed to perform well on many kinds of real-world data... The algorithm finds subsets of the data that are already ordered, and uses the subsets to sort the data more efficiently. This is done by merging an identified subset, called a run, with existing runs until certain criteria are fulfilled."

About number 7:

"... Also, it is seen that galloping is beneficial only when the initial element is not one of the first seven elements of the other run. This also results in MIN_GALLOP being set to 7. To avoid the drawbacks of galloping mode, the merging functions adjust the value of min-gallop. If the element is from the array currently under consideration (that is, the array which has been returning the elements consecutively for a while), the value of min-gallop is reduced by one. Otherwise, the value is incremented by one, thus discouraging entry back to galloping mode. When this is done, in the case of random data, the value of min-gallop becomes so large, that the entry back to galloping mode never takes place.

In the case where merge-hi is used (that is, merging is done right-to-left), galloping needs to start from the right end of the data, that is the last element. Galloping from the beginning also gives the required results, but makes more comparisons than required. Thus, the algorithm for galloping includes the use of a variable which gives the index at which galloping should begin. Thus the algorithm can enter galloping mode at any index and continue thereon as mentioned above, as in, it will check at the next index which is offset by 1, 3, 7,...., (2k - 1).. and so on from the current index. In the case of merge-hi, the offsets to the index will be -1, -3, -7,...."

Comment: I cannot see any relationship between the minimum size of the run for which insertion sort is used (OP's question) and the number of elements taken from the same run during merge which triggers gallop mode (your answer).